# How to implement Part Of Speech tagging for a given String array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, part-of-speech

i need a simple English POS tagging program to be implemented in c# only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem goes to the domain of Natural Language Processing. Look at this library : [SharpNLP](https://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/), you can process a good range of english language here.

and [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) is a tutorial on how to do things in NLP, its python example but sure you can convert it to C#

Also check [this](https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordPOSTagger.html) for .net, basically you need a dictionary for a particular language, and call the NLP classes to match against it.